# Trying to run a netsh batch with foreign characters

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt, netsh, ascii, ansi

I am trying to run a batch file with the following content:

```
 netsh interface ip>set dns "Połączenie lokalne" source=dhcp
```

The file is saved as ANSI. My Windows codepage is **1250**, the OEM one **852**.

Thus, since Windows uses ANSI (ACP) while the console uses ASCII (OEMCP), the letters "ł" (B3) and "ą" (B9) [Windows-**1250**] get turned into "│" (B3) and "╣" (B9) [CP **852**] respectively.

The attempt to *work around this**:

> @echo off for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x
>   chcp 1250>nul
>
> netsh interface ip>set dns "Połączenie sieci bezprzewodowej" source=dhcp
>
> chcp %cp%>nul

does not work. (Probably since netsh is a seperate interface?)

**as specified by Metalcoder here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584423/problem-running-bat-cmd-file-with-accented-characters-in-it*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.